# How to list all SSIDs on which ADB Wireless is allowed?

Tags: adb, settings, system, developer-options, wireless-debugging

When connecting a phone to ADB wirelessly, the user must allow Wireless Debugging on the current wifi network, with an option to remember the preference.

Is there a way to programmatically read the list of SSIDs on which Wireless Debugging has been permanently allowed?